# Add New Column in Admin user manage table

Tags: joomla-3.x

How do I add an extra column in the admin user manage table? I want the registration form to have a unique member number for me to assign a new user with, I then also want the member number to be shown on the user manage list for me to search with. Is this a possibility?

Seen how to add a new field to the registration form but not sure how to connect it to the user database table, and display it on the user manage list.

Comment: Welcome to JSE. What have you tried yourself so far? We are here to help, however please show your own findings first.

Comment: Hi Lodder, haven't tried anything, been trying to find some information on it but haven't had any luck.

Comment: This question could benefit from some context.  What exactly do you intend to add?  Your question may be deemed Too Broad or Needs More Focus.  I'd rather your question stay open, so please show us what documentation pages were nearly helpful while you were researching -- include the actual links in your question.  Right now your question is seeking a complete tutorial to satisfy your "requirement dump" -- these types of questions are less attractive for volunteers to answer because they ask for disproportionately more effort from the volunteer vs the effort you have shown in your question.

Comment: You might want to explore using Joomla custom fields too. You can add a field which is logically associated with a user, but just not stored in the user table. See https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields. I'm assuming you're on a fairly recent version of joomla. I would advise against tampering with Joomla core tables, as a rule.